# display post according to the term

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy

I want display all my taxonomy terms on the left side of my website, so that when a user clicks on one of the terms he can see the posts according to it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create template according [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). Place your design + posts loop inside. To list your custom taxonomy use [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

Comment: thanks for your help but how can i display all taxonomy on one place i cant figure it out

Comment: place wp_list_categories function with your arguments winto place where you want to list it. see examples section on link above.